# SqlException, Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion ... where do I increase this timeout period?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I keep getting this timeout error in a rather larger report generation using LINQ to SQL.

> w3wp.exe, NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
>   SERVICE, SqlException, Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>   prior to completion of the operation
>   or the server is not responding.
>   ...
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, 7, NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, False,
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)

In web.config I have added Connect Timeout = 3600 to the connection string but it happened again, is that the right way to increase this timeout?

Is it done through web.config or maybe IIS? Need to increase it in the meantime while I work on optimizing this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to set the [CommandTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout.aspx) on your DataContext.

Comment: The page you linked says 'This default value is set by the storage provider. Note that some providers may throw exceptions if this value is set to a non-zero value.' So that makes me think I can change this in SQL Server 2005 so I can fix immediately while we wait for patch day. Any idea how this would be done?

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but if it's a dev environment that you don't mind experimenting on, you can try sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 600
GO    
RECONFIGURE
GO  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177457(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: thanks, that must not be it because it is set to default 600 already which is 10 minutes, and the thing times out anywhere from 30-90 seconds... ah I see: "This value has no effect on queries received by the Database Engine." that's probably why, looks like a patch is going to have to be the solution :)